# The named parameter 'title' isn't defined. Issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Issue

> The named parameter 'title' isn't defined. Issue in flutter

Code:

```dart
 items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
              title: Text(
                'Chat',
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.alarm_add),
              title: Text('Reminder'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            // BottomNavigationBarItem(
            //   icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
            //   title: Text(
            //     'Profile',
            //   ),
            //   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            // ),
          ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `label` instead of `title` on [`BottomNavigationBarItem`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html).

It will be like

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
```

More about [`BottomNavigationBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) and [`BottomNavigationBarItem`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html).